# How can I add a fixed vertical menu to my site?

Tags: plugins, menus, navigation

I'd like to have a vertical (secondary) menu on some sub-pages of my site. It should be fixed (will stay as the viewer scrolls down the screen). I'm currently using the Q2W3 fixed widget, but it lacks the customization options I'm looking for...wondering what other options are out there?

Comment: Use StickUp jQuery library or anything like so. Or, you can use a simple CSS `position:fixed; top:0` solution to the problem. And it's not in the scope of WordPress

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to WordPress myself, but I think answering questions is a good way to learn. There may be a way to use hooks, but I couldn't figure that out, so went ahead with directly editing header.php.

I tried the following:

From Appearance, Menus, I added a new menu and named it Vert_Menu_test

I chose to add the menu to the top left corner of my test site: In my header.php file, at the very beginning of the body, I added this code (based on [this doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu))

```
<?php
$defaults = array(
//'theme_location'  => '',
'menu'            => 'Vert_Menu_test',
'container'       => 'div',
//'container_class' => '',
'container_id'    => 'vert-menu-div',
//'menu_class'      => '',
//'menu_id'         => '',
'echo'            => true,
'fallback_cb'     => false,
//'before'          => '',
//'after'           => '',
//'link_before'     => '',
//'link_after'      => '',
'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
'depth'           => 0,
//'walker'          => ''
);
wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
?>
```

I gave the container div the id "vert-menu-div". (See above.) So, in style.css, I added

```
#vert-menu-div {
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

This was enough to get the basics. A vertical menu fixed to the top-left corner. Good luck.